# Why can't a type alias use associated constants from the original type in Rust?

Tags: types, rust, alias, associated-const

Editor's note: As of Rust 1.43, this works as expected.

---

I have a type alias `type CardId = u64;` and I want to initialize it to the maximum number it can have through the `std::u64::MAX` constant. And was surprised to learn that I cannot do the same from the alias.

```rust
use std::u64;

type CardId = u64;

fn main() {
    let this_works = u64::MAX;
    let this_doesnt_work = CardId::MAX;

    println!("Max amount in integer: {} and {}", this_works, this_doesnt_work);
}
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0604b7fe00921bef59d33dbcc4b246fb)

I was expecting the `MAX` constant to be accessible from the type alias also. This would aid me when I would change the type to u32, and this causes the code to have two points where I would need to modify instead of just location of the type alias. Why was this decision made, and did I miss something which which maybe would make this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before Rust 1.43, constants such as `std::u64::MAX` were not associated constants of the `u64` type but constants defined in a module called `u64`. 
This is legacy from when Rust didn't have associated constants.

As of Rust 1.43, those constants are defined as associated constants of the corresponding types.
There is currently [an RFC opened to deprecate the modules](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/e3de748ae48650d7b33325b8917e929a8e08e1b9/text/0000-associated-constants-on-ints.md). For now they are only ["soft-deprecated"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/97bdd31b0eab51d0a51b8746123f910cd868dff3#diff-35afb383a78a1ee775142944d5b5d126) and the documentation notes:

> ## Constant std::u32::MAX
>
> ```rust
> pub const MAX: u32 = u32::max_value(); // 4_294_967_295u32
> ```
>
> The largest value that can be represented by this integer type. **Use [`u32::MAX`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#associatedconstant.MAX) instead.**

(Emphasis is mine)

Another way to do this is to use the associated `const` methods (eg. `u32::max_value`) which were added because constant methods were available before associated constant. Those are also soft-deprecated and the documentation notes:

> ```rust
> pub const fn max_value() -> u32
> ```
>
> **This method is soft-deprecated.**
>
> Although using it won’t cause compilation warning, new code should use [`u32::MAX`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#associatedconstant.MAX) instead.
>
> Returns the largest value that can be represented by this integer type.

(Emphasis is *not* mine)

---

Associated constants are also accessible via type aliases as you expect:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    const FOO: u32 = 42;
}

type Bar = Foo;

fn main() {
    let this_works = Foo::FOO;
    let this_also_work = Bar::FOO;

    let this_works_too = u32::MAX; // As of Rust 1.43

    println!("The answer: {} and {} or {}", this_works, this_also_work, this_works_too);
}
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61bfdd4e9e1d37e4d002730915310f34)

Answer (score 7):

##### These information are outdated, please see [mcartons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840330/1021920) for a better solution

---

This is because [`std::u64::MAX`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/u64/constant.MAX.html) is a module constant, not a type constant.

You can use [`max_value`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#method.max_value) if you want to use it with a type alias:

```rust
use std::u64;

type CardId = u64;

fn main() {
    let this_works = u64::max_value();
    let this_does_work_as_well = CardId::max_value();
    
    println!("Max amount in integer: {} and {}", this_works, this_does_work_as_well);
}
```